# Can't remove all the other files but those in one variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, filtering

I have a script that filters my logs, but the problem is that when I would like to delete everything else but certain files I get errors of Unrecognized escape sequence. I've been trying to split the values but it seems that nothing works. I also tried -exclude before, but didn't get it to work. It's supposed to remove all the other files but $result and $clr.

```
$files = @()
[xml]$photonconfig = Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PhotonServer.config

$photonconfig.SelectNodes("Configuration/*") | Select-Object -Expand Name | % {
    $_.Replace("xxx","")
} | ForEach {
    $files+= Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log\log/*$_*.log |
             sort -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |
             Select-Object -First 3 
}

$result = $files | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -First 3
$clr = "PhotonCLR.log"

$all = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log\log/* |
       Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch $result } |
       Remove-Item
```

Comment: This script is a bit confusing. Why, say, `$files+= Write-Output ""`?

Comment: For easier debug, try and avoid long pipeline constructions. Things akin `something | something | something | % | something` are very easy to mess up. Assign results into temp variables, so intermediate results are easy to check.

Comment: What's your actual error message?

Comment: Yeah, I edited the script a bit, forgot to delete the write-output before after testing.

Comment: Error: parsing "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log\log\xxx.log C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log\log\xxx
0.9.5-20180103.log C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log\log\xxx0.9.5_Photon.log" - Unrecognized escape sequence \U.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\yhty.ps1:18 char:80
+ ... Desktop\log\log/*  |  where-object {$_.Name -notmatch $result} | remo ...
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second operand of the `-match` and `-notmatch` operators is a regular expression, not an array of file names. Use the `-contains` operator instead:

```
... | Where-Object { $result -notcontains $_.Name } | ...
```

On PowerShell v3 and newer you can also use the `-notin` operator, which feels a little more "natural" to most people:

```
... | Where-Object { $_.Name -notin $result } | ...
```

Note that for this to work you also need to expand the `Name` property when building `$result`:

```
$result = $files | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -First 3 -Expand Name
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed my script!